# How to remove all rows that DON'T contain a specific string, which are spread over multiple columns

Tags: sqlite

Using an SQLite query, I'm trying to remove all rows that DON'T contain a specified string. This string could be spread throughout multiple columns.

**Example:**
As visualised in the image below, I want to remove all rows that don't contain the string "Steel".

[image]

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this in SQLite?

Comment: What does *remove* mean. Do you want to delete the rows or you need a SELECT query? Also, are the empty columns values nulls or empty strings?

Comment: @forpas deleting them preferably. The empty values are nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` in the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM tablename
WHERE 'Steel' NOT IN (COALESCE(col1, ''), COALESCE(col2, ''), COALESCE(col3, ''), ...);
```

Change `col1`, `col2`,... etc to the names of the columns that may contain `'Steel'`.

`COALESCE()` is needed because `NOT IN` should never be used to make comparisons to nulls.